# Redirection after successful insertion & mailing using foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, phpmailer

**Code explanation:**

The given provided code is about ordering the items in a ecommerce website and trigger the php mailer to send cart items on a specific email address via email and it also insert the items into database at the same time.

**Done so far:**

I had manage to insert the records into DB and also sending/trigger the same records into mail address successfully.

**Problem:**

Once the cart items inserted into the database successfully and mail is triggered here I want to redirect the user to checkout.php page...once everything done successfully also want to unset the `unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);` cart session.

Lets say I have 3 items into my cart, so then this foreach loop will loop 3/same times to insert to the records into DB. using `break;`/`die();` at the end of the loop will not benefit. loop will stop after 1st loop and only 2 items will add into db if we use break.

I made this code to **redirection** and **unset** the shopping card but don't know where to apply or how to apply it inside the loop. Any guidance or best way to do this will appreciated.

```
 if($run==true)
 {
    header('location:../checkout.php');
    unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);  
     $run=false;
  }
```

**Complete code:**

```
$run = true; 
$shown=0;
$order_prefer = 1;      
if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])|| $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] =='') {   
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            No orders have been placed - We can only process your order with at least 1 order.</div>';
    } else {
        //include email template parts
        include "src/order_send/part_1.php";
        include "src/order_send/part_2.php";
                            
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $number => $val) {
            // prepare and bind
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO purchase
                                    (guest_code,productid,quantity,
                                    date_purchase,time_purchase) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("siiss",
                                    $_COOKIE['CODE'],
                                    $val['product_id'],
                                    $val['product_quantity'],
                                    $current_date,
                                    $current_time); 
            $stmt->store_result();  

            if($stmt->execute()) {
                $st = $conn->prepare("SELECT productid, productname 
                                        FROM product WHERE productid= ?");
                $st->bind_param("i",$val['product_id']); 
                $st->bind_result($productid,$productname);
                $st->store_result();
                $st->execute();
                while ($st->fetch()) { 
                    $json=array('pid'=>$productid,'pname'=>$productname);
                    
                    $body .='<tr>
                                <td><center><span class="badge  text-center" style="background: #65cc0b;">'.$order_prefer.'</span></center></td>
                                <td>'.$json['pid'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$json['pname'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$val['product_quantity'].'</td>
                            </tr>';
                    $order_prefer++;        
                }

                $st->close();
                $stmt->close(); 

            }else{
                //show msg only once
                if($shown==0) {
                    echo 'ERROR: while placing your order. Please contact restaurant owner';
                    header('location:../checkout.php?er=true');
                    $shown = 1;
                }

                $st->close();
                $stmt->close(); 

                }
                                                       
           if($run==true) {
                    header('location:../checkout.php');
                    unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);  
                    $run=false;
            }
        }


            //include email template parts
            include "src/order_send/part_3.php";
                                     
            $status_query ="SELECT status from mailing";
            $sq=$conn->query($status_query);
            $main_result =$sq->fetch_array();
            if(isset($main_result['status']) && $main_result['status']=='ON') 
            {
                $mails->msgHTML($body);
                $mails->Subject = 'Incoming order';
                $mails->send(); //echo 'error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: if you look at the end of the complete code you will note I had already implemented it, results give unset the session_cart in the 1st loop of foreach.

Comment: Do not redirect in foreach loop. You should set / unset your $run flag and redirect after foreach loop.

Comment: @Viswanath Polaki thanks for response, could you explain more brief? what condition should I will apply in if?

Comment: After insertion and email sending you should redirect the user ( i.e after foreach loop ). Once user is redirected your code written below header location will not execute.

Comment: By doing the now foreach is in infinite loop. because somehow the unset is not executed and foreach session allways has items in it.